# Connecting to mysql database with c program

Tags: mysql, c, database, connector

I would like to connect the mysql database using C in CodeBlocks

1. I downloaded MySQL Connector C 6.1
2. I added this below to my linker settings
   [image: linker settings]
3. I added this to Compiler in Search directories
   [image: Search directories]
4. I copied libmysql.dll to my project directory and /windows/system
5. I added #include "mysql.h" to my hello world example and tried to compile it.

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "mysql.h"    
    int main()
    {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
    }
   ```

When I try to compile it I get following errors:

> cannot find `-l-lmysqlpp`
>
> cannot find `-l-lmysqlclient`

I would be grateful for any help.

EDIT:

1. Let me upload my test_build_log.html file

```
-------------- Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
gcc.exe -o bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\main.o "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\libmysql.lib" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\vs12\mysqlclient.lib" -l-lmysqlpp -l-lmysqlclient
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l-lmysqlpp
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -l-lmysqlclient
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I believe this `-l-lmysqlpp` should be `-lmysqlpp`  What compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: GNU GCC Compiler/Windows 10

Comment: Then the first comment is correct.  If this is the error/warning you are getting, then there is likely something entered incorrectly in your linker settings.  Do you have an empty string listed somewhere that would result in the `-l` showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cannot find -l-lmysqlpp
cannot find -l-lmysqlclient
```

These should be presented to the linker as:

```
-lmysqlpp
-lmysqlclient
```

The repeating `-l` switch indicates something wrong in your linker settings.  Make sure there are no entries (including spaces or other hidden characters) in both `link library` an d `Other linker options` boxes.  You may need to clear and re-enter everything in each box.

One more think to try, view the actual compile command line that is being used:
Code::Blocks can output a build log.  Settings->Compiler and debugger->Global compiler settings->{slide tabs to the right}->Build options tab->Save build log to HTML.  Turn this feature on, then view the log after your next attempt.  There may be something there pointing to the problem.

Comment: I have no idea why this additional -l appears beofre those lines. I have only two entries in the linking settings (it can be seen on the first picture I posted).
Also here's my Build Log:
` gcc.exe  -o bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\main.o   "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\libmysql.lib" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\vs12\mysqlclient.lib" -l-lmysqlpp -l-lmysqlclient `

Comment: @user3742046  See edit. Take a look at the build log, after you turn that feature on.

Comment: I finally got this. Those additional linker options were added in the Debug tab. When I deleted them everything works fine. Thanks